# Flutter Material different border colors with radius not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add border color on 3 side only and add border radius seems like in container its not possible i tried its showing some error then i try it with Material and its working fine but issue is i am not able to add borderRadius now. Need to know how can i add border radius with different side colors.

Want to achieve this

[image]

And stuck on this

[image]

You can see on left side no radius is showing

My code

```
                     Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Material(
                          shape: Border(
                            left: BorderSide(
                              width: 1,
                              color: Color(0xffE6E6E6),
                            ),
                            bottom: BorderSide(
                              width: 1,
                              color: Color(0xffE6E6E6),
                            ),
                            top: BorderSide(
                              width: 1,
                              color: Color(0xffE6E6E6),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            width: Width * 0.45,
                            height: Height * 0.07,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5)),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              'https://facebook.com/',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: textGreyColor, fontSize: 15),
                            )),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: Width * 0.45,
                          height: Height * 0.07,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            key: ValueKey('name'),
                            style: TextStyle(color: textGreyColor),
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(5)),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Color(0xffE6E6E6), width: 1),
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                                  color: textGreyColor, fontSize: 15),
                              hintText: "Facebook Page",
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Color(0xffE6E6E6), width: 1),
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(5)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it with ClipRRect. Not the best solution but it will work

```
               Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5)),
                      child: Material(
                        shape: Border(
                          left: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Color(0xffE6E6E6),
                          ),
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Color(0xffE6E6E6),
                          ),
                          top: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Color(0xffE6E6E6),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          width: Width * 0.45,
                          height: Height * 0.07,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5)),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            'https://facebook.com/',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: textGreyColor, fontSize: 15),
                          )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: Width * 0.45,
                      height: Height * 0.07,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        key: ValueKey('name'),
                        style: TextStyle(color: textGreyColor),
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(5)),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xffE6E6E6), width: 1),
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                              color: textGreyColor, fontSize: 15),
                          hintText: "Facebook Page",
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xffE6E6E6), width: 1),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(5)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Flutter expect that when you will use the border radius all border will be uniform. So using a custom style for 2 or 3 border and setting a border radius after that does not work.

You can use a `outer container` which will have the border and radius of four side. After that you place a `ClipRRect` to cut any background color if that goes over the outer container border. Here's a example output
[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double borderRadius = 6;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius)),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
            ),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius)),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  //left child
                  Expanded(
                    child: _facebookUrlText(),
                  ),
                  //middle separator
                  Container(
                    width: 1,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  //right child
                  Expanded(
                    child: _facebookPageInputField(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
          // in the middle of the parent.
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _facebookUrlText() {
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Color(0xffFAFAFA), //background color of left box
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'https://facebook.com/',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _facebookPageInputField() {
    return TextFormField(
      key: ValueKey('name'),
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1),
        ),
        filled: true,
        hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),
        hintText: "Facebook Page",
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```